# How to display more than one column in a listbox?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a userform to search for a person in a 10000 entry Excel, using any of the NO, Firstname, lastname, username or email column.

When the listbox displays the data, it only displays the first column, and not any of the other four columns.

```
Private Sub SearchCommand_Click()

Me.ResultListbox.AddItem

For a = 1 To 5
    Me.ResultListbox.List(0, a - 1) = Sheet1.Cells(1, a)
Next a

Me.ResultListbox.Selected(0) = True

End sub
```

[image]

Comment: You should add an explanation of the problem you are having and what you are trying to achieve so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

My version of Excel automatically set the listbox column number to be 1. So I wrote:

```
Me.ResultListbox.ColumnCount = 5
```